# Fetching a File From FTP Using Php

Tags: php, ftp

I am trying so fetch a file from another server into my server using the ftp in php.

There were two steps. The first step is to send the file from my server which I have done successfully.

Now I need to fetch a file from the warehouse ftp server. I connect to it successfully as well as get the list of files from there too. But I do not know how can i fetch it. For sending here is the code. I tried switch between MY SERVER and The Warehouse server but it does not work and keeps on saying the file doesnt exist where as file is there.

Any ideas?

Here is the code for sending the file

```
$ftp_server    = SERVER_IP;
$ftp_user_name = FTP_USER;
$ftp_user_pass = FTP_PASS;
$ftp_dir       = "public_html/inbound/";
$mode          = "list_xml_files";
$file          = "";

if ($file_list = ftp_list_xml_files ($ftp_server,$ftp_user_name,$ftp_user_pass,$ftp_dir,$mode,$file)) {

$ftp_server    = WAREHOUE_SERVER;
$ftp_user_name = WAREHOUSE_FTP_USER;
$ftp_user_pass = WAREHOUSE_FTP_PASS;
$ftp_dir       = FILE_DIRECTORY;
$mode          = "ftp_to_warehouse";

foreach ($file_list as $v) {

if ($file_uploaded = ftp_list_xml_files ($ftp_server,$ftp_user_name,$ftp_user_pass,$ftp_dir,$mode,$v)) {

echo "FILE SENT";

}

else
{

echo "ERROR";

}


function ftp_list_xml_files ($ftp_server,$ftp_user_name,$ftp_user_pass,$ftp_dir,$mode,$file) {

$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server); 
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

if ((!$conn_id) || (!$login_result)) { 
        echo "FTP connection has failed!<br>";
        echo "Attempted to connect to $ftp_server for user $ftp_user_name<br>"; 
        exit; 
    } else {
        #echo "Connected to $ftp_server, for user $ftp_user_name";
    }

switch ($mode) {
    case "list_xml_files":
        $contents = array();
        ftp_chdir($conn_id, $ftp_dir); // Change Directory
        // get .xml files in the current directory
        $contents = ftp_nlist($conn_id, "*.xml");
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// What if there's no files to process?
        if (count($contents) > 0) {
            // output $contents
            // print_r($contents);
            // exit;
            return $contents;
        } else {
            return FALSE;
        }           
        break;
case "ftp_to_warehouse":
        // upload the file
        $source_file = 'tracking_number_xmls/pending/' . $file;

        ftp_chdir($conn_id, $ftp_dir); // Change Directory
        $destination_file = $file;

        $upload = ftp_put($conn_id, $destination_file, $source_file, FTP_TEXT); // FTP_BINARY

        // check upload status
        if (!$upload) { 
            echo "FTP upload has failed!<br>";
            return FALSE;
        } else {
            echo "Uploaded $source_file to $ftp_server as $destination_file<br>";
            return TRUE;
        }
        break;

default:
        echo "Nothing Done<br>";
}

// close the FTP stream 
ftp_close($conn_id);
} // end function
```

Comment: Try [ftp_get](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-get.php)

Comment: I have tried it but it always gives error that file not found...

Comment: Remember to use the full server paths to the directories you are working on. Server paths are not the same as "ftp paths"

Comment: ok so if i have the server ip which is "123.456.789.1" and the file is in public_html/folder, what will be its full path?